# How to return fields from running Windows service using ASMX Web Service?

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-services, asmx

I've some static Engine class running in windows service, and I want to return Engine's some fields using web service.(simple ASP.NET web service)

How can I do this?

when I simply write in my web service:

```
return Engine.SomeField;
```

It creates new instance of Engine end works with that, which is different from Engine running in windows service, even if it's marked as static.

Comment: I assume you're using a WCF service for this. I'd rather not make assumptions, but since you haven't supplied any details, I have to just make a guess.

Comment: It's Asp.NET web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an ASMX web service (aka ASP.NET web service) inside of a Windows Service. Only WCF has the ability to be hosted inside of anything other than IIS.

Comment: Can you give some samples or articles how to do this with WCF? I've no experience with WCF

Comment: If you have no experience with WCF, then you do not need an example. You need to learn the fundamentals of WCF. See [WCF Beginners Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) and [tag:wcf].